# How did Hagrid put Fluffy in the room in the third floor?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

*Fluffy is a large, vicious, three-headed dog who was once cared for by Rubeus Hagrid. Fluffy's greatest weakness is the inability to resist falling asleep to the sound of music.*

> Hermione: "That thing has a name?"
>
> Hagrid: "'Course he's got a name, he's mine."

We know that Hagrid put Fluffy as one of the obstacles to the Philosopher's Stone in 1992.
And we know that it was **very large** and only Dumbledore and Hagrid know how to get past Fluffy.

- How was Hagrid able to put such a large animal in a room on the third floor, through small doors?
- What happened to it after?

Comment: I'm guessing magic... I mean they can probably shrink him down to a manageable size right?

Comment: Ohh its funny...@DoctorWho22 ..if they can,why couldn't others like professor Quirrell  make it like a puppy and get pass through trap door...No need of Harp and others..Even if it was that much easy surely Dumbledore shouldn't have think about that dog

Comment: He likely used a doggie door.

Comment: a monster sized Doggie door?That couldn't be a doggie door at all.:)..

Comment: Well, they surely could have used a *Reducio* spell to shrink him, and then an *Engorgio* to put him back to his original size. After that, Dumbledore could have cast certain enchantments on him that prevent anybody else from casting spells on Fluffy!

Comment: Rather then changing Fluffy, why not just assume the enlarged a Window and lifted him up.

Comment: @Zoredache good point...

Comment: Transfiguration is also a possibility. If you take Draco down to weasel size, mass is obviously not an issue. So, transfigure him to a hat rack or whatever, then change him back in the room.

Comment: I'm afraid,@JohnP Transfiguration has many limitations ...i may not be possible to transfigure a monster dog..

Comment: very carefully.

Comment: Speculation: They put him in Newt's case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Canon does not tell us how old Fluffy was when he was placed in the castle. He may have still been a puppy when put into the room on the third floor, in anticipation of him growing big enough to guard the Sorcerer's Stone. Hagrid does have a history of raising monstrous beasts in the castle (Aragog). In the same vein, Fluffy may not have been fully grown at the time he was guarding the stone, yet still have been very, very big, but manageable for Hagrid.

Or, perhaps a Shrinking Solution was used, as Snape used on Neville's toad Trevor in *Prisoner of Azkaban*. Once Fluffy was in place, the antidote could be given, returning Fluffy to his normal size. Only one person (Hagrid, presumably) would be needed to administer a Shrinking Solution and its antidote.

> [Snape] trickled a few drops [of Shrinking Solution] down Trevor’s throat.
>   There was a moment of hushed silence, in which Trevor gulped; then there was a small pop, and Trevor the tadpole was wriggling in Snape’s palm.
>   The Gryffindors burst into applause. Snape, looking sour, pulled a small bottle from the pocket of his robe, poured a few drops on top of Trevor and he reappeared suddenly, fully grown.
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 97 - Bloomsbury - chapter seven, *The Boggart In the Wardrobe*</sub>

Comment: I know I have no specific lines from the book, but didn't Dumbledore state that each of the current teachers, including Quirrel, had contributed a test? That would mean, because of the curse on the DatDA post, that it had to have been within the last year. Of course, we don't know how quickly Fluffy grew, so I may be off base.

Comment: This presents the same problem as before quirrell could have just gotten shrinking solution and given it to fluffy.

Comment: Actually, the Shrinking Solution would have been one of two choices for Quirrell -- he could have chosen Shrinking Solution *or* music. He clearly chose music and was none the worse for the wear. Enchanting a harp and having Fluffy fall immediately asleep is infinitely easier than administering a Shrinking Solution to a three-headed dog (maybe you have to dose all three heads, who knows?). But the fact remains that Shrinking Solution was an available choice to Quirrell. We know from canon that he didn't use it. I see no problem with suggesting Shrinking Solution as an option.

Comment: Where did quirrel used shrinking potion on fluffy @Simon....

Comment: Yes @Slytherincess ..Dumbledore and Hagrid could have used Shrinking potion...

Comment: Could you not lace some meat with shrinking solution? As quirrell was stuck on  getting past fluffy for sometime.

Comment: @Simon - Sure, I suppose so.

Comment: One practical use Shrinking potion is in the transportation of livestock — it allows for a wizard to carry an entire herd of pigs in the pocket.[check here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Shrinking_Solution)

Comment: @Slytherincess I agree with your point..Shrinking solution.

Comment: It's very hard to make an enraged dog to drink something you give it to him, and even if you try to throw laced meat, it's one thing if you throw it over a fence into a garden and wait, and it's another thing if you are in the same room with a giant enraged dog who is jumping towards you. By the way, guard dogs can be trained to not accept food from strangers. So Hagrid could have used potions, but for Querrelmort it would be very impractical if not outright impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Three explanations spring to mind:

1. **Magical effort.** Hagrid placates him with music, and a teacher/several teachers shrink him to a manageable size. Given how Fluffy is clearly a magical beast there could be some magical resistance that has to be overcome and therefore several teachers may be needed.
2. **Hercules-style.** Based on the 12th labour of Hercules; defeat a cerberus (on which Fluffy is based), except Hagrid placates him with music rather than beating his dear pet into unconsciousness. Being half-giant and massively strong, he simply drags Fluffy through the castle and into the room. Sure, the door's tiny, but magic could probably enlarge the doorway.
3. **Dumbledore did it.** He can apparate within Hogwarts, and I wouldn't put it past him to be able to carry 'excess luggage' along with him. Poof, problem solved.

Comment: 1.If several teachers could shrink the fluffy,then Quirrel also can do that...2.Fluffy is different from that so called Cerberus...3.Are you sure that wizards can apparate with animals.. **Apparition is a magical form of teleportation, through which a witch or wizard can disappear ("Disapparate") from one location and reappear ("Apparate") in another and a witch or wizard must be 17 years old or older and have a licence to Apparate**

Comment: @Mani Not that I agree with IronWaffleMans answer but your comment gives unreasonable answers in response. 1. If it could several teachers, then Quirrel would not be able to do it. It would take several teachers for a reason, it is more reasonable to say that in this scenario Dumbledore couldn't do it on his own so how would Quirrel. 2. He didn't say it was the same he just said Fluffy is based on Cerberus which he is. 3. I am not sure if you can disapparate with Animals you can with people so it is a likely assumption. I'd have to look at canon for that.

Comment: ok.. @Simon .I agree with you.I mean to say that Quirrel was not the only person there, The Dark Lord with him.

Comment: I think it is impossible to shrink,so Quirrel decided to get the secret from Hagrid by givig a dragon egg to him.

Comment: @Mani The dark lord was at his weakest when possessing Quirrel,

Comment: @IronWaffleMan **Dumbledore did it** that solves everything..+1

Comment: Possible extension of 1 and 3: A team of house-elves were needed to both overcome that magical resistance and deal with Fluffy's size

Answer (score 2):

As it is, we cannot take any fact of how he was moved from canon so everything here is speculation based on canon. Some people disagree with speculative answers but it is enjoyable to share my perspective on someone's question.

- So firstly; Fluffy could've been put to sleep via music and then Hagrid, Dumbledore and it would be safe to assume Mcgonagall and Snape by the very least possibly even Professor Sprout. (Basically all the Witches and Wizards involved with placing protection around the Philosophers stone). They would help to moved Fluffy towards the room where the doorway would be enlarged. They would use magic or possibly in Hagrids case strength.
- Secondly; This would only involve Hagrid and Dumbledore, the doorway would again be enlarged however this time Hagrid would lure or lead Fluffy towards and into the room. (Based on how large Fluffy was we can safely assume that Hagrid must have to have had some control over him - he can't have slept all the time)
- Thirdly; This is probably the most ridiculous perhaps a Portkey was used. We know they are used to transport large volumes of wizards from across to world.

I don't think Dumbledore would be able to side-along apparate Fluffy, it is not in canon whether you can side-along apparate an animal let alone a Massive (Size would also come into play) one.

I don't think you would be able to reduce Fluffy in size, look at how wizards handle dragons they have to get several wizards to stun the dragon. If they could reduce dragons they would, it would be much easier for transport.

Comment: :- Very nice point about the dragons...

Comment: but only two persons know the secret about fluffy's weakness..So others were not involved in case of fluffy.

Comment: @Mani The second point is indeed the most supported, or more accurately the one with the least amount of doubt behind it.

Comment: Yes ,as it was completely related to magic..we can say that any thing possible with magic.

Comment: @Mani Well we know doorways can be resized in Hogwarts the RoR does it on it's own.

Comment: Yes...it is possible.

Comment: lets us assume that they brought fluffy to the Hogwarts grounds by some means(as same as dragons) and then a spell on a harp and **Locomotor charm** to move to third floor...

Comment: @Mani I would agree but it seems that (to me) Fluffy would be too large for one or two wizards Locomotive charm. I think we can agree he was moved manually through an enlarged door somehow by which I mean not teleported in or shrunk.

Comment: the way they brought Dragons from romania....

Comment: @Mani Got a quote?

Comment: @Mani - Yeah, I'd like to see a quote verifying the dragons were ... however you're saying they were brought from Romania. That would be great! Remember there's a shrinking potion, guys: Shrinking Solution. Snape uses it on Trevor the toad in *Prisoner of Azkaban*. See my answer for the quote. :)